# Google App Engine Python, Jquery and Javascript for a cascade select

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine

I tried a lot of tutorials and forums but I can't find how to make a cascade select work in the Google App Engine !

I tried this code, I have two selects but... it's not a cascade select... The second select is the same even if I change the first select choice...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/jquery.chained.js"></script>


<select id="mark" name="mark">
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="bmw">BMW</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="series-3" class="bmw">3 series</option>
  <option value="series-5" class="bmw">5 series</option>
  <option value="series-6" class="bmw">6 series</option>
  <option value="a3" class="audi">A3</option>
  <option value="a4" class="audi">A4</option>
  <option value="a5" class="audi">A5</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#series").chained("#mark");
</script>
```

and here my app.yaml file :

```
application: ***
version: 10
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: guestbook.application

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

I always have in the second select "3 series" "5series" "6 series" "A3" "A4" "A5" !

Can you help me ?

Comment: Does your `jquery.chained.js` file load? Do you see any errors browser's DevTools console? Temporarily try `<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuupola/jquery_chained/master/jquery.chained.min.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="jquery.chained.js"></script>` and if that works your app.yaml static file handlers are not properly set.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is still here ! I've juste edited my question and I think that now my app.yaml file is correct (I have downloaded the jquery.chained.js file and put it in the js folder of the app). The link you gave me to test didn't make it work neither..

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser's DevTools console? Does it work locally/remotely/neither?

Comment: There is no error in the log console : INFO     2014-10-15 15:52:44,444 module.py:640] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6659
INFO     2014-10-15 15:52:44,538 module.py:640] default: "GET /stylesheets/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-10-15 15:52:44,546 module.py:640] default: "GET /js/jquery.chained.js HTTP/1.1" 404 154

And it doesn't work nor locally neither remotely :(

Comment: I meant look in your **browser's** DevTool console, not your GAE launcher's for errors, but what you provided also clearly shows that `GET /js/jquery.chained.js` returns 404 which is the problem. Also try `<script src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained/jquery.chained.min.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="/js/jquery.chained.js"></script>` there seems to be some utf8 character in my first suggestion that might break things or maybe you aren't allowed to include from github since that didn't work for me either but this new include works just fine.

Comment: It works !!! Thank you ! Why that ? Can I use your link for my projet or do I have to modify my app.yaml ? And if yes how ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use that link for your project without website's permission, it was for testing only, you should fix your `app.yaml` (see the answer below) and use your own links unless it's a CDN from google/jquery/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you uploaded your `app.yaml` it's clear that the issue happens because your:

```
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

route should go before

```
- url: /.*
  script: guestbook.application
```

The `/.*` will redirect **all** requests that were previously not matched to your `guestbook.application` handler which knows nothing about the static files and the `/js` handler will never have a chance to serve any requests.

Once you fix that make sure you change your include back to `<script src="/js/jquery.chained.js"></script>` since it's generally not nice to include from other websites without their permission.

Comment: Thnakyou a lot for the solution ! I edited my app.yaml and change the link you gave me for <script src="/js/jquery.chained.min.js"></script>‌​ and it works well ! Thank you again !